# login to and access data from a website - postman works

Tags: c#, post, authentication, get, postman

i'm trying to login to a website and reach the data that belongs to the loginned user. the website is mubi.com. in postman, i can "post" login information, succesfully login and then "get" the ratings of the people i followed. when i tried on c#, i can login succesfully again by posting login information. it returns my user's information with no errors. and then when i tried to "get" the ratings of the people i followed it is unsuccess. it behaves as i'm not logged in. when getting this info in postman i don't post or send any information to get the ratings as i don't do too on c#. what shall i do? do you have an idea?

ps: also the postman says there are no cookies even though the interceptor is enabled.

Comment: It's about cookie.The next Get request doesn't contains the cookie which used to identity user returned from the last login Post request.

Comment: yeah it mus be about the cookies but as i noted down the postman doesn't show any cookies. or is there a way to get the cookies after the successful login process?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you forgot the Authorization Key?
the login service can be used without this key, because you don't have an Authorization-Token until you login.

ps: sorry for answering, i wantet to comment, but i ain't got 50 reputation yet

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `HttpClient` which will store cookie last response set.
see [HTTP request with post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/http-request-with-post).